# Conformal mapping of gapped field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Assume a 2d cft defined on a plane with the action $S_0$. Consider a relevant perturbation, $S = S_0 + g\int d^2x O(x,\bar{x})$, where $g$ is a small but finite parameter and $O(x)$ is a primary field. The theory has no scale invariance any longer. For such gapped theories, can one still apply conformal mapping to study them and write down the new action $S_\omega$ in which the perturbation term follows $O(x,\bar{x}) = \left(\frac{d\omega}{dx}\right)^h \left(\frac{d\bar{\omega}}{d\bar{x}}\right)^\bar{h} O(\omega,\bar{\omega})$ ($S_0$ is invariant). For example, map the plane to cylinder to study the entanglement properties? Or in another way, is conformal mapping a good approximation to the first order of $g$?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from performing a conformal mapping on your theory, it simply won't be invariant under the mapping after you've broken the conformal symmetry. Are you really asking about specific applications to theories with conformal invariance and how well these applications work when one perturbs the theory?

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Sorry, I didn't get it. Maybe I didn't express the question clearly. My question is can one write down the new action $_\omega$ in which the perturbation term follows $O(x,\bar{x}) = \left(\frac{d\omega}{dx}\right)^h \left(\frac{d\bar{\omega}}{d\bar{x}}\right)^h O(\omega,\bar{\omega})$ ($S_0$ is invariant).

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: In general you can't, even for dilatations, because beta-functions can be non-trivial.